# VBA numeric colour values for Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am using Access 2013 and am finding difficulty in understanding which colour code is being used above all once a theme is setup..

As an example, I have a text box which has the following colour code in the properties box:

Sfondo 1, Più scuro 5%
(sorry for the Italian)

i need to simply find a way to get the 8 digit code so I can put it into VBA.

I would be amazed if there is not some simple way to get this but up until now I have spent countless hours researching the matter with minimal success..

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the actual color (and hence the numeric value) would depend on the currently-selected Theme, but you can get the numeric value by using VBA to dump the corresponding property (for example, `.BackColor`) of a Form or Report object.

For example, I added a Text Box control to a form and used the Property Sheet to set it's `Back Color` to `Background 1, Darker 5%`. Then in the `On Load` event handler for the form I did a

```
Debug.Print Me.txtComments.BackColor
```

and when I open the form I see

```
 15921906
```

in the Immediate Window of the VBA editor.